# Why does my code find the wrong item to remove on click event?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

From a list of articles, I delete one of them by getting the articleId with data(). When I first delete, it works well. But when I delete again, the data() gets the former articleId rather than the current articleId. When I look into the event.target, the articleid in the dataset is the correct, current one. What's wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```js
remove: function(e) {
    var articleId = $(e.target).data("articleid");
    if (confirm("are you sure to delete the article？")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: config.api.deleteArticle[0].replace("<article_id>", articleId)
                                        .replace("<studio_id>", cookie.getCookie("studioId")),
        type:config.api.deleteArticle[1],
        success: function() {
          this.reload();
        }.bind(this),
        error: function() {
          alert("fail");
        }
      });
    }
  },
  reload: function(sortType){
    $.ajax({
      url:config.api.getArticles[0],
      success:function(d){
        this.setState({articles:d.articles});
      }.bind(this),
      error:function(){
        alert("fail");
      }
    });
  },
 render: function() {
     var self = this;
      var content = this.state.articles.map(function(article) {
            return (
          <span className={(self.props.manageOn)?"article-delete": "article-delete hidden"} data-articleid={article.articleId} onClick={self.remove}>删除</span>
                                 );
       }
       return (
         <div>
              {content}
         </div>
       )
 }
```

I wonder whether it is because the react diff?

Answer (score 0):

Could be react diff issue.
When you render multiple items, in your case the spans, react wants to have a key attribute.

Try adding `key={article.articleId}` to your span component. That may solve the issue.